# Как получить путь к картинке и внести в модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.btn').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
    $('.modal.img-cont').prepend("<img src='" + img + "'>");
    console.log(img);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Модальное окно-->
<div id="smallModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Заказ</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="order_form" action="zakaz.php" method="post" onsubmit="if(this.name.value==''){alert('Введите Ваше имя!');return false}if(this.phone.value==''){alert('Введите Ваш номер телефона!');return false}return true;">

          <center>
            <div class="img-cont"></div>
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя">
            <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон">
            <button class="btn">Заказать со скидкой</button>
          </center>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>

<li class="product type-product post-1769 status-publish last instock product_cat-kusochki-30pack product_cat-30pack product_tag-assorti product_tag-cats has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-bundle"><a><span class="gtm4wp_productdata" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;" data-gtm4wp_product_id="1769" data-gtm4wp_product_name="Набор ассорти для кошек 30 шт" data-gtm4wp_product_price="2870" data-gtm4wp_product_cat="Наборы 30 шт" data-gtm4wp_product_url="#" data-gtm4wp_product_listposition="4" data-gtm4wp_productlist_name="General Product List" data-gtm4wp_product_stocklevel="" data-gtm4wp_product_brand=""></span><img width="324" height="324" class="tov" src="https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-324x324.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" srcset="https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-324x324.jpg 324w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-150x150.jpg 150w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-300x300.jpg 300w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-768x768.jpg 768w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-416x416.jpg 416w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-100x100.jpg 100w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px"><noscript><img width="324" height="324" class="tov" src="img/tov1.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="микс для кошек" srcset="img/tov1.jpg 324w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-150x150.jpg 150w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-300x300.jpg 300w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-768x768.jpg 768w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-416x416.jpg 416w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-100x100.jpg 100w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px" /></noscript>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Набор ассорти для собак 21 шт</h2><span data-for-kittens="false" class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">2 849&nbsp;
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8381;
                </span></span></span>
    </a><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smallModal" style="background:pink;border-radius:12px;padding:15px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;line-height:30px;outline:none;border:none;cursor:pointer;padding:5px 15px;">Заказать</a></li>
```

Мой код не работает

Comment: Откуда выкопал тег `center`???

Comment: @Air переделаю без него

Comment: Он просто мертвый... Из-за этого у тебя может полететь много чего... Просто учти это

Comment: @Air спасибо за совет, Вы не подскажите в чём моя ошибка в скрипте?

Comment: Alexander, прости, но я с `JQ` вообще не дружу... я люблю  чистый `JS`, Если бы мог тебе помочь, то помог бы... Не переживай, найдутся помощники...

Comment: И еще не выдержал и поковырялся в твоем коде. Есть еще одна важна вещь, не надо вещать события клика на тег `<a></a>`, у тега `<a></a>` есть свой обработчик, он же придуман для ссылок, сделай лучше `div`...

Comment: @Air спасибо, исправлю

Comment: И кто тебе сказал, что твой код не работает... По крайней мере ссылку выдает

Comment: @Air у меня есть код который мешает, буду искать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не хватает пробела вот в этом селекторе .modal.img-cont

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.btn').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
    $('.modal .img-cont').prepend("<img src='" + img + "'>");
    //return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Модальное окно-->
<div id="smallModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Заказ</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="order_form" action="zakaz.php" method="post" onsubmit="if(this.name.value==''){alert('Введите Ваше имя!');return false}if(this.phone.value==''){alert('Введите Ваш номер телефона!');return false}return true;">

          <center>
            <div class="img-cont"></div>
            <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя">
            <input name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Введите телефон">
            <button class="btn">Заказать со скидкой</button>
          </center>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>

<li class="product type-product post-1769 status-publish last instock product_cat-kusochki-30pack product_cat-30pack product_tag-assorti product_tag-cats has-post-thumbnail shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-bundle"><a><span class="gtm4wp_productdata" style="display:none; visibility:hidden;" data-gtm4wp_product_id="1769" data-gtm4wp_product_name="Набор ассорти для кошек 30 шт" data-gtm4wp_product_price="2870" data-gtm4wp_product_cat="Наборы 30 шт" data-gtm4wp_product_url="#" data-gtm4wp_product_listposition="4" data-gtm4wp_productlist_name="General Product List" data-gtm4wp_product_stocklevel="" data-gtm4wp_product_brand=""></span><img width="324" height="324" class="tov" src="https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-324x324.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="" srcset="https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-324x324.jpg 324w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-150x150.jpg 150w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-300x300.jpg 300w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-768x768.jpg 768w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-416x416.jpg 416w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21-100x100.jpg 100w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/korm-dlya-sobak-superpet-assorti-21.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px"><noscript><img width="324" height="324" class="tov" src="img/tov1.jpg" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="микс для кошек" srcset="img/tov1.jpg 324w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-150x150.jpg 150w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-300x300.jpg 300w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-768x768.jpg 768w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-416x416.jpg 416w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix-100x100.jpg 100w, https://superpet.me/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/korm-dlya-koshek-superpet-mix.jpg 1000w" sizes="(max-width: 324px) 100vw, 324px" /></noscript>
        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Набор ассорти для собак 21 шт</h2><span data-for-kittens="false" class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">2 849&nbsp;
                <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#8381;
                </span></span></span>
    </a><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#smallModal" style="background:pink;border-radius:12px;padding:15px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;line-height:30px;outline:none;border:none;cursor:pointer;padding:5px 15px;">Заказать</a></li>
```

Comment: спасибо, у Вас всё работает, но у меня видимо что-то мешает, в модальное окно не записывается тег img